# PHP display set number of sibling pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a piece of PHP code for Wordpress to display 3 sibling pages of the current page, with their featured image and title linking to the relevant page. At the moment I have the following code that outputs all the sibling page names and thumbnails but I need to tweak it so it only displays three, with the post title and thumbnails both linking to the sibling page, and has a link and h4 around them. Any ideas...? 
Thanks

```
<div class="list_related">
<?php global $post; //not neccessary if used in the loop
$parent = $post->post_parent; 
if( $parent ) :
    $siblings = get_pages( 'child_of=' . $parent . '&parent=' . $parent . '&exclude=' . $post->ID);
    if( $siblings ) foreach( $siblings as $sibling ) :
        //start of whatever you need to output//
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($sibling->ID,'thumbnail');
        echo $sibling->post_title;
    //end of whatever you need to output//
    endforeach;
endif; //ends if( $parent ) //
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to limit it to 3, you can change you're `get_pages()` line to this:

```
$siblings = get_pages( array(
        'child_of' => $parent,
        'parent'   => $parent,
        'exclude'  => $post->ID,
        'number'   => 3  //this part limits it to 3 
));
```

Then you can change your `foreach` loop too look like this

```
if($siblings): foreach($siblings as $sibling):?>
    <h4>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($sibling->ID);?>">
            <?php echo $sibling->post_title;?>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($sibling->ID, 'thumbnail');?>
        </a>
    </h4>
<?php endforeach; endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Max! However that second foreach part doesn't validate properly for me? I have the below... I have tried to tweak it to display correctly but not sure... Thanks so much..

`code` if( $siblings ) foreach( $siblings as $sibling ) :
        //start of whatever you need to output//
        echo "<h4>";
        echo "<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($sibling->ID);?>"></a>";
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail($sibling->ID,'thumbnail');
        echo $sibling->post_title;
     echo "</h4>";
    //end of whatever you need to output//
    endforeach;`code`

Comment: You needed an `endif;`, i've updated my code to include your `if` statement.